# Better English equivalent for "set of methods"

Tags: etymology, phrase-requests, neologisms

In the philosophy of science, there are three terms which are used to describe three different related notions. In both Polish (pl) and German (de), these three terms are unique such that there is no risk of equivocation. Briefly:

- metoda (pl); Methode (de)
  an ordered sequence of actions chosen to economically and efficiently achieve a desired end
- metodyka (pl); Methodik (de)
  a set of methods chosen for the purpose of achieving a common end or related ends (e.g. the cluster of methods used in molecular biology)
- metodologia (pl); Methodologie (de)
  the science whose proper objects of study are the previous two

In English, metoda is *method*, while both metodyka and metodologia are *methodology*. In English, we have the word *methodic*, but this is an adjective, and if I were to invent a word such as *methodics* or the noun form *methodic*, it would appear, given the Greek etymology of similar terms (concerning the -ikos ending, e.g. mathematikos, logikos, physikos) and the meanings of words with similar endings in English, that the word would suggest a field of study. Oddly enough, *methodology*, etymologically speaking, does concern a field of study and is thus the wrong word to describe the second term above.

Is anyone aware of an alternative that would work? If no such alternative exists, any ideas about what new word could be coined to better suit the intended meaning?

EDIT: If anyone is able to read Polish, here is a [PDF](http://goo.gl/B9muq)   with definitions supplied by Herbut.

Comment: Don’t coin a new word.  Use *set of methods* if you must.

Comment: Possible alternatives: Technique, algorithm, etc.

Comment: @coleopterist - Technique and algorithm are subclasses of method, so those won't do. Remember, I'm not talking about a single method, but a body of methods.

Comment: From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methodology): "In theoretical work, the development of paradigms satisfies most or all of the criteria for methodology. A paradigm, like an algorithm, is a constructive framework, meaning that the so-called construction is a logical, rather than a physical, array of connected elements."

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just say "method system" or "method framework"? I still think methodology would work, even if it is also a field of study.

Comment: I agree with brobdingnagian.  Methodology is serviceable and understood, despite the etymology.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - "Methodology" is the currently used term for both. But my question isn't about the current usage, but a desire for a better term.

Answer (score 2):

When I was in the LitCrit racket, *methodology* meant essentially your *metodyka*, representing both the embrace of a particular set of *methods* and the application of those *methods* to a particular problem.

Critical study and examination of differing or opposed *methodologies* had no distinct name; when it was necessary to refer to such study it would be called something on the order of *methodological inquiry* or *methodological controversy*.

Of course LitCrit has never embraced a single body of methods; the situation may be quite otherwise among scientists or philosophers of science. But I suggest that if your discourse requires a third term, the one that English lacks is the equivalent of your *metodologia*.

For that, *methodics* would serve admirably, and I cannot imagine a context in which it would be confused with *methodic* (which is in case pretty rare--*methodical* is far more [usual](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=methodic%2Cmethodical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)).

Or you could go back to the source of the problem. The title of Descartes' pioneering inquiry is usually expressed in English as *A Discourse on Method*--no article, no suffixes, just *Method*.

Comment: I'll go with this. Within which I think the key point is that English doesn't have a single standard term for *"the science of methodology"*. But I don't see that as a problem, since I'm far from convinced we ever actually need such a term "for real" - but your suggested *methodics* might be useful to alert us that wherever we see it, we're probably looking at something closely related to [fruitloopery](http://quantumfruitloopery.com/)

Comment: I think it's a serious field of study. One of my all-time favorite works, Polanyi's *Personal Knowledge*, is largely about this "methodics".

Comment: I don't know that, but I think he's the "tacit knowledge" guy. I'm probably sounding off above my pay grade, but *personal/tacit knowledge* sounds like stuff to do with how *individuals* think, acquire & organise their knowledge, etc. Whereas I'd like to hope there's a single approach called "***the*** scientific method" that everyone could/should in principle sign up to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, he's the "tacit knowledge" guy. What he argues is that scientific knowledge is at bottom created and sustained by passionate personal commitment, not mere mechanical application of an abstract "methodology".

Comment: @Stoney - Interesting proposal, although it may be difficult to incite a shift from "methodology" to "methodics", and I find the use of "methodology" to describe anything but the study of methods etymologically bad, albeit common practice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - We're getting a little off topic here, but, assuming I understand you correctly, I'm not sure why you think the science of methodology can be lumped in with "fruitloopery".

Comment: @danielm: Well, if I skim through the relatively few instances of ["the science of methodology"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+science+of+methodology%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, it seems to me it often occurs in "non-science" contexts. Which is not the case with, say, ["the science of biology"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+science+of+biology%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Maybe "methodics" truly is a science in want of a name, but I remain to be convinced (maybe it's just part of *epistemology*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Depends on what you mean by "non-science context". Methodology of science, for instance, is related to philosophy of science. Furthermore, it's not a question of there not being a name for it, b/c there is ("methodology"). It's that I find it very bothersome that the same term is used to describe both the "study of method(s)" and "a proper object of study of the field" while referring to two different things. To make matters worse, one object of methodology's study is itself. So you have two things named "methodology" which are studied by methodology.

Comment: @danielm  But at what point do you contemplate stop multiplying ologies? When you've gotten past M1(=metoda) to M2(=metodyke) to M3(=metodologia), what are you going to call M4, the study of competing M3s? And what, when you have exhausted M4, will the next generation call M5?

Comment: @StoneyB - I think you're overcomplicating things. No multiplication of -oligies ever occurs. M1 and M2 are objects of study of the field M3. M1 and M2 are not themselves fields of study, and do not relate to one another in that way (M2 is but a multiplicity of M1s). There is no M4 (and no one is competing necessarily :). When I say M3 can be its own object of study, this is merely a reflexive relationship (i.e. you are studying the methods used in methodology), and thus what you call M4, M5, etc, are nothing more than M3. Philosophy in general is in a similar position.

Answer (score 1):

Methodology is defined in both the AHDEL and Collins as the English counterpart of both *metodyka* and *metodologia*. In fact, the *metodyka* sense is given first in each dictionary, showing that this is the meaning that one might consider more basic - in spite of the -ology ending. This is how I would expect the senses to be prioritised, and matches the situation with *ideology*. If the *metodologia* sense is required and context will not make this usage clear, 'methodology proper' could (rather perversely!) be used.